# MYSQL PHP veriable not working in WHERE IN() CLAUSE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$ci = implode('&#39,&#39', $_GET['city']);

$res = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM data WHERE (date BETWEEN '$dd1' AND '$dd2') AND (city IN('$ci')) ORDER BY id DESC")or die (mysql_error());
```

If i `echo $ci` than it shows value `JND','RJT','ABD` but not working with variable

if i put directly  `city IN ('JND','RJT','ABD')` thn it works..

using veriable not perfoming query

Comment: Why are you imploding on an html entity? SQL <> HTML.... SQL doesn't care that &#39 is rendered as a quote in a web browser, because SQL isn't a web browser

Comment: @MarkBaker  checkboxes values aray

Comment: What has checkboxes values array got to do with the fact that you're imploding on an HTML entity and then expecting SQL to understand what you mean? SQL understands quote characters like `'`, but not HTML entities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check your query text

```
$ci = implode("','", $_GET['city']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE (date BETWEEN '$dd1' AND '$dd2') AND (city IN('$ci')) ORDER BY id DESC";

echo $query;

$res = mysqli_query($link,$query)or die (mysql_error());
```

Comment: Try to change to `$ci = implode("','", $_GET['city']);`.

Comment: What happened? Do you found a mistake? )

Comment: SQL understands quote characters like ' and my mistake was writing ascii code of quote

Comment: Oh, I skipped your comment `thnks donee its working`. )